# Quiz Game , how to add the question to the other scene? use database? or other way?

Tags: unity-game-engine, save

I want to add questions to the other scene, so the other scene can keep it. If I have a lot of questions to add, which is the best way to use.

**Way 1:**

I think i could use a database. But I don't know how to check the length of questions.

**Way 2:**

Maybe there is another way so i don't need to use a database?(I tried PlayerPrefs ,but it can't save a lot of things.)

**What i would like to achieve:**
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pnhd.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would just serialize your questions into a file. The file can be binary, json, xml or whatever u prefer, then would load them into a storage class when the game starts.

**Why not database?**

Database would be an overkill in this scenario Imho, unless your game can be played online, and users can add questions.

**Why not Player Prefs?**

Player preferences are a good way to store, some simple values, like storing a score in an extremely simple game, like Temple Run etc.., but for storing hundreds of questions it is not suitable.

So things you should check.

- Serializing data in unity.
- Check what is json
- Saving classes into binary

**The way i would go with:**

Json/Xml has the cool thing that it can be directly edited in the file, because it stores your values as strings. Because you have "questions" (Which prolly have a question, + 4 answers) you could just, extend and edit the already existing questions in that file and the next time you load unity those questions would pop up, while if you would go with binary, you would not be able to edit your questions as easily.

**Some tips:**

- **You can't directly serialize `MonoBehaviour` classes!**
  (Make a storage class for it and serialize that one.)
- Also if you only want to pass like 5-10 questions, and you have a component that has those questions you can just use `DontDestroyOnLoad(questionHolder);` [DOC](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html), this would allow you to not destroy your `questionHolder` component during loading a new scene.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Maybe I don't say clear.  My quiz game already can work. I just want add some new function. Like the game end , player can add the question in to a notebook ,that player can review the question . So , how to add the question from scene1 to scene2 ,like my picture say.

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand. If there have different questions in each round. Is it still work?

Comment: Since it dont allows your monobehaviour to be destroyed yes it will preserve it

Comment: ok.  I have a problem that can I add the words to json in game time? or it's only add from start? (if it's  can work , can it  keep before and add the new one?)

Comment: `You can't directly serialize MonoBehaviour classes!` don't the [Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) explicitely state `The API supports any MonoBehaviour-subclass, ScriptableObject-subclass, or plain class/struct with the [Serializable] attribute.`?

Comment: Note that `PlayerPrefs` should never be used for storing game progress .. also not scores etc. As the name says they are ment to store rather "meaningless" Player preferences like e.g. Music Volume, Difficulty level .. etc